# UIFont(name: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10).fontName, size: 10)?.fontName == UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10).fontName is false in iOS13

Tags: ios, arrays, uifont

I tried to create a UIFont instance using the font name of the system font.

```
enum Font {

    static var scaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.0

    case system(_ size: CGFloat)
    case systemBold(_ size: CGFloat)

    var dynamic: UIFont {
        switch self {
        case let .system(size):
            return UIFont(name: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1).fontName, size: size * Font.scaleFactor)!
        case let .systemBold(size):
            return UIFont(name: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 1).fontName, size: size * Font.scaleFactor)!
        }
    }
}
// UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10).fontName -> ".SFUI-Regular"
// but UIFont(name: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10).fontName, size: 10)?.fontName -> "TimesNewRomanPSMT"
// and also UIFont(name: ".SFUI-Regular", size: 10)?.fontName -> "TimesNewRomanPSMT"
```

That way, I get another font named "TimesNewRomanPSMT" only for system fonts. I think it worked fine before iOS13.
I'm using Xcode 11.0 at macOS 10.15 beta